# Why is my PHP keep saying "Please upload an image"?

Tags: php

I'm trying to have the registration come out to "You are successfully registered" by having the image transferred into the images folder. However, it keeps passing it, and goes to the else statement: "Please upload an image."

I've looked over the logic and syntax, and it looks correct. But, can't register correctly.

```
HTML & PHP:

<?php

include('connect.php');

$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // VARIABLES STORAGE
    $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['size'];


    // LOGIC
    if(strlen($firstName) < 3) {
        $error = "First name is too short.";
    }
    else if(strlen($lastName) < 1) {
        $error = "Last name is too short.";
    } 
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = "Please enter valid email address.";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 8) {
        $error = "Password must be greater than 8 characters.";
    }
    else if($password !== $passwordConfirm) {
        $error = "Password does not match.";
    }
    else if($image == "") {
        $error = "Please upload an image.";
    }
    else {
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, email, password, image) VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$password','$image')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$insertQuery)) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_image,"images/$image")) {
                $error = "You are successfully registered!";
            }
            else {
                $error = "Image is not uploaded.";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="formDiv">
        <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label>First name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="fname" /><br /><br />

        <label>Last name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="lname" /><br /><br />

        <label>Email:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />

        <label>Password:</label><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />

        <label>Re-enter Password:</label><br />
        <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" /><br /><br />

        <label>Image:</label><br /><br />
        <input type="file" name="image" /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$password','$image')` no no no no you're going to make me cry http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You might want to check what restrictions apply to file uploads / post-requests on your server. Using phpinfo() you get most of it. Additionally, `var_dump($_FILES);` to get clue of what is contained in the array.

Comment: @Isaac I don't understand why this is incorrect? I'm having the user inputs' values placed into the database table?

Comment: @user3385997 what if `$firstName` were set to `hacked haha','-','-','-','-'); Drop Table users; -- get rekt` goodbye `user` table. Did you not read the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excerpt from your code:

```
$tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['size'];
```

Because you use the same variable name on the 2nd line, you're overwriting the image `tmp_name`, so your script loses access to the file.

You can just delete the 2nd line, since you don't use image size in the rest of the script. Or rename it `$img_size` if you plan to use it.

Comment: Thanks, @BettleJuice. That did the trick. I'll look into the image size at a later time.